# Pick a photo or take a photo and use onActivityResult() for both not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm trying to create an app were i can either take a new photo or use an existing one. I get both functions to work separatly but not together. The application crash when the `Uri imageUri = data.getData();` runs.

Here is the code:

```
 public void btnPhotoClicked(View v) {

    //Use to invoke a Camera
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //Create a variable with the filepath generated by the android operating system, Like a baws

    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    if (pictureDirectory.exists()) {
        File test1 = new File(pictureDirectory, "100MEDIA/");
        if (test1.exists()) {
            pictureDirectory = test1;
        } else {
            File test2 = new File(pictureDirectory, "100ANDRO/");
            if (test2.exists()) {
                pictureDirectory = test2;
            } else {
                File test3 = new File(pictureDirectory, "Camera/");
                if (!test3.exists()) {
                    test3.mkdirs();
                }
                pictureDirectory = test3;
            }
        }
    } else {
        pictureDirectory = new File(pictureDirectory, "Camera/");
        pictureDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    String pictureName = getPictureName();
    File imageFile = new File(pictureDirectory, pictureName);
    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);


    //Start intent and anticipate result
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);
}
```

and here is the code for the `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    //if we are here everything processed successfully

    if (requestCode==IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        //If we are here we came from the Välj existerande build
        Log.d("MainActivity", data.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "IMAGE GALLERY_REQUEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //the address of the image on the device SD-card
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        //Declare a stream to read the image data from the SD-card
        InputStream inputStream;

        //Getting a Input stream based upon the image uri
        try {
            //if it execute flawlessly
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            //show the image to the user

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //show massage saying if the image is unavailable
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        //We are here because we have received a result from the camera
        Toast.makeText(this, "CAMERA RESULT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("MainActivity", data.toString());
        //the address of the image on the device SD-card
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        //Declare a stream to read the image data from the SD-card
        InputStream inputStream;

        //Getting a Input stream based upon the image uri
        try {
            //if it execute flawlessly
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //show the image to the user

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //show massage saying if the image is unavailable
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: What happens? do you get any error? can you share the logcat of the errors here? :)

Comment: WIN DEATH: Window{4333a8f8 u0 com.example.akerberge.greifincident/com.example.akerberge.greifincident.MainActivity}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of image uri

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == 1) 
            {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) 
                {
                  if (temp.getName().equals(tempFile)) 
                  {
                        f = temp;
                        //File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tempFile);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions); 
                    final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 100;
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator;

                    File file = new File(path,tempFile);

                    updPath=file.toString();
                    imgSel = true;
                    success=true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
            else if (requestCode == 2) 
            {
                try
                {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = { MediaColumns.DATA };
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    File outputPath= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tempFile);
                    updPath = outputPath.toString();
                    copyFile(picturePath, updPath);

                    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(updPath));
                    final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 100;
                    thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail,THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearroutstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,bytearroutstream);
                    img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    imgSel = true;
                    success=true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use File class in place of Uri Dont go with whole code just try part of it and change your code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The default Android camera application returns a non-null intent only when passing back a thumbnail in the returned Intent. If you pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` with a URI to write to, it will return a `null` intent and the picture is in the URI that you passed in.

You can verify this by looking at the camera app's source code on GitHub:

- https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java#L1186

Thereof your app crashes. Because `getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri)` invoke method of null object. `imageUri` is null.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT):

> **public static final String EXTRA_OUTPUT**
>
> Added in API level 3
>   *The name of the Intent-extra used to indicate a content resolver Uri to be used to store the requested image or video.*
>
> Constant Value: "output"

So, you call `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, you should pass extra like this:

```
Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri uri  = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/photo.jpg");
photo.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(takePicture,requestCode);
```

and then in *onActivityResult*:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "photo.jpg");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                bitmap = crupAndScale(bitmap, 300); // if you mind scaling
                pofileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: In this answer what does picture in -----> picture.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri); <---- mean?

Comment: `Uri uri  = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/photo.jpg");` - this is an URI of your image file. In this file will be saved image data from camera

Comment: Sorry for it. I fixed this mistake

Comment: The problem here is that i can't receive the foto from inside the else if, becuase i need to know the exact name

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg, name of what? You can define it as constant, for example `public static final String BUFFER_PHOTO_FILE = "file:///sdcard/blablabla.jpg"` and use it when you need. I don't understand your problem. Please describe it more detail. I realy want to help you but, I don't understand you. Why need know exact name and why you can't use some default name like BUFFER_PHOTO_FILE?

Comment: i use a function called  getPictureName() wich gives the image a name, then i pic it up within the function to put it in the imageview.

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg, firstly, call `getPictureName()` and save result to class member, for example 'String mPictureName'. Then when you start activity to capture image do this: `Uri uri  = Uri.parse(mPictureName)` and pass it like this: `photo.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);`. Then in `onActivityResult` open file `mPictureName`, it will be your capured photo